# Fallout 4: Putting DiMA on trial

Tags: fallout-4

I'm having an issue with one of Far Harbor's two main quests, so here's a spoiler-free description of what's happening:

---

Playing on PC, have done all quests for Far Harbor, have all four settlements going and over 65 happiness. During the quest "[The Way Life Should Be](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Way_Life_Should_Be)", I convinced DiMA to turn himself in. My plan was to talk down the crowd from attacking Acadia, then help the Children meet their precious Atom. However, DiMA's trial doesn't go as planned:

- When Allen speaks, I have both the "Shut up" AND "Acadia is innocent" speech checks. Neither makes a difference, though.
- The Mariner speaks up on my behalf.
- Cassie Dalton speaks up on my
  behalf.
- Mitch speaks up on my behalf.
- Teddy Wright speaks up, but
  instead of mentioning the Rite of Passage I passed, he instead says
  that people went to Echo Lumber on my word and haven't been heard
  from since.
- Small Bertha does not speak, even though I completed
  "Turn Back the Fog".
- Andre does not speak, even though I cured him.

At that point, after Teddy speaks, everyone elects to attack Acadia - even if I pass the difficult "Acadia is innocent" check. Is this a bug or did I miss something?

P.S. - I did NOT notify Allen about the evidence or have Teddy examine it, but I DID tell Avery about it and promise to keep it secret before confronting DiMA. Could that be what's killing my good vibes?

P.P.S. - I went back to a save from before approaching Avery, but still had the same results. So apparently I did (or didn't do) something earlier on that determined this outcome.

---

Note: I do have a lot of mods loaded, but nothing related to Far Harbor. Just to be safe, though, I de-activated all of my mods and tried again. Same result.

Comment: Just a tip, you can add spoilers by using the >! tag before a message. So you can use, for example, without quotes ">! Darth Vader is Luke's Father and so on and so forth

Comment: @Retrosaur - oh I know, but I purposefully worded the question so there aren't any spoilers. Had I gone into any detail about the reasons for the trial, I surely would have put it in spoiler tags.

Answer (score 5):

I did all the quests before **The Way Life Should Be** and make DiMA to turn himself in and stopped the attack. Only mod I used was **Unofficial Fallout 4 Patch**.

My only presumption is that your mods corrupted your save game. There are some mods that overriding core mechanics of game and even after uninstall/disable corruption in save still persist.